# reverse referencing in query lookups that span relationships

Tags: django

In [Django official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#making-queries), there is an example as below,

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    number_of_comments = models.IntegerField()
    number_of_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

In below lookup,

`>>> Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon')`

**Q:** Even though one foreign key defined in `Entry` class is pointing to `Blog`, but there is no `entry` field defined in `Blog` class, how can above lookup refer to `Entry` class from `Blog` in the form of `entry__headline`?
I did not see anywhere in official doc authorize this kind of usage..

Comment: To add to @Amin's answer, [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) might also help

Comment: the hyperlink you shared is exactly what i was looking for.  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In `Entry` model there is a FK to `blog` and you can use it's model name, `entry` for looking up

When using `entry__headline__contains='Lennon'`, django gets that you want to look up in a related model with `entry` name, and then can do look up for you

But for accessing `entry` model via `blog` query, you should use its `related_name` . you can find about it in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Comment: In this example, is there a direct way to query the Blog model to get a list of blogs with at least N entries written by an author with a specific email?